# iMac (mid 2010, 27") minimum ram slots required to fill

Tags: imac, memory

Can I use only two 8 GB RAM modules with my mid 2010 27" iMac (2.8 GHz Core I5)? In other words, do you have to fill all 4 memory slots or are 2 filled slots sufficient?

Comment: They were sold in configurations with only two slots filled I believe, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

#### The short answer to your question is “yes”.

But, why would you limit the memory given the low price of memory modules today?

According to [Everymac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.8-27-inch-aluminum-mid-2010-specs.html), your "official" max is 16GB, however you can go all the way up to 32GB.  I personally used Crucial memory modules in my iMac and MacBook Pro with no problems.

I would go with [2 16GB kits](http://radnex.us/Crucial-PC3-10600-16GB-Kit-Mac) for a total of 32 GB RAM (a "kit" being 2 8GB modules; a total of 4 8GB RAM modules).

[image: Everymac.com memory screen grab]

Comment: Just because it will take 4x8 doesn't necessarily mean it will take 2x16. I'd stay within Everymac's recommendation.

Comment: @Tetsujin  - 2 16GB kits = 4 8GB SODIMMs

Comment: That's not particularly clear in your answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin "I would go with 4 8GB RAM Modules (or 2 16GB kits)"